# Including blank lines following region in fold

Tags: vim, syntax, folding

I'm currently attempting to improve the folding behavior of Matlab files in Vim. I have a syntax file generated and the folding behaves as I want with one exception. Say I have the following code:

```
function [out1,out2] = doSomething(arg1,arg2)
    out1 = performSubRoutine(arg1);
    out2 = performSubRoutine(arg2);
end

function output = performSubRoutine(input)
    output = input;
end
```

When I perform the folding I get:

```
+---  4 lines: function [out1,out2] = doSomething(arg1,arg2)

+---  3 lines: function output = performSubRoutine(input)
```

Ideally, I would like to have the fold engulf any trailing whitespace.

My region definition from the syntax file is:

```
syn region matlabClassBlock     
            \transparent fold 
            \matchgroup=matlabClass 
            \extend start='\<function\>'        
            \end='\%([%-+(\*\:(\/\[]\s*\)\@<!\<end\>\%(\s*[-+}\:\*\/()\]]\)\@!.*\($\n^\s*\)*$'re=e 
            \contains=ALLBUT,@matlabClassCluster,@matlabProceduralCluster
```

I used the offset specifier `"re=e"` to say that I want to fold to the end of the match, but I still get the first result.

I must be missing something, because the documentation states that the offset method should work. Any ideas?

Comment: What trailing whitespace do you want folding to hide?  Do you refer to a blank line between two folded functions?

Comment: Yes, can you update your question to include an example of your desired output, please?

Comment: I think it might be a Vim bug or feature. If you change your end pattern to `'^$'re=e` (i.e. match empty lines), then the empty line still isn't included in the fold. If, on the other hand, you change your end pattern to `'^ $'re=e` (i.e. match a line containing a single space and add a single space to the line after the first 'end' in your test case, then that line **is** included. I think empty lines must be treated specially for syntax-based folding.